# How to debug only socket.io connection without Node.js site in WebStorm/PhpStorm?

Tags: node.js, sockets, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm developing a site which is in PHP. In this website I'm creating chat. Now problem is that I can't debug properly in WebStorm/PhpStorm.

This is command which I was using now in cmd before

```
node -r dotenv/config server.js
```

for debugging I'm using `console.log` which will write socket server data in cmd and client side socket data in browser console.

I want to shift to IDE debugging. I use PhpStorm and sometimes WebStorm. Both are same in JavaScript handling.

This is configuration I've done in PhpStorm:

[image: Nodejs Debug configuration]

The problem is breakpoint is not working on socket receiver in server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const serverConf = require("./serverConf");
const server = serverConf.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {'pingTimeout': 5000, 'pingInterval': 1000});

serverConf.startServer(server);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("admin_send_text", async function(response) {
        response.admin_id;
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Breakpoint is on *response.admin_id* line

Because I'm not using any routes so I can't debug socket connection. It's just move to next line. Like no breakpoint is there.

This is a message I receive in terminal

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" -r dotenv/config C:\xampp\htdocs\gofashion\chat\server.js DEBUG=*
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61037/1e06be2f-b94f-41c4-bbc8-a7437dcd2d4d
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

How to do I set breakpoint on socket receiver on server?

Comment: works for me using similar setup - execution is suspended on breakpoint, and I can see received data in the debugger. BTW, you can get more logging from socket.io if you add `DEBUG=socket.io*` to *Environment variables* section odf your **Node.js** run configuration

Comment: but execution doesn't suspend for me. It keeps going. *DEBUG=socket.io** doesn't stop execution

Comment: ` DEBUG=socket.io*` is not supposed to suspend it, it just enables debug logging. Unfortunately, I can hardly help unless you provide a project that shows up the issue

Comment: In the configuration described in the queestion the breakpoint will never be reached.
Do you call the listener? I'm missing the snippet of code with which you connect to your socket.io-endpoint of your express server. A simple html with ```[...] io.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:61037'); io.emit('admin_send_text', {admin_id: '123456'}); [...]``` should be enough. If desired, I will write an more detailed answer.

Comment: Obviously I'm emitting text from client side and it reaches server and continue doing what I have written to do but the problem is that breakpoints doesn't work on that. i.e above mentioned sample "admin_send_text" is called after emitting from client but breakpoint doesn't work on it and also inside callback function

Comment: I found the problem. I was running the app using Shift+F10. Now I'm using Shift+F9 to debug and it's working. Also I switched to debugger tab in debug terminal to view variable value which I made breakpoints on.

Comment: Problem is solved by me. How would I close this bounty?